# Plotly: How to define custom steps for coloring and legend in plotly.express.imshow?

Tags: python, plot, plotly, data-visualization

I am using `plotly.express.imshow` to plot a correlation matrix of my continuous variables. Is it possible to define a custom legend that contains more 'fine' steps?

Here's an example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px

# load example data set
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

# get correlation matrix
iris.drop('species',inplace=True,axis=1)
iris_correlations = iris.corr()

# plot correlation matrix using px.imshow
px.imshow(iris_correlations)
```

which gives you:
[image]

I would like to change the step-size in the legend to 0.1 instead of the automatically generated 0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily change the step size through the `dtick` attribute for the coloraxis of the colorbar like this:

```
fig.update_layout(coloraxis = dict(colorbar=dict(tickmode = 'linear',
                                                 dtick = 0.1)))
```

When it comes to the colorscale itself, you're using a continuos color scale, so I don't think you can make it "finer" than that. Please correct me if I'm wrong though.

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px

# load example data set
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

# get correlation matrix
iris.drop('species',inplace=True,axis=1)
iris_correlations = iris.corr()

# plot correlation matrix using px.imshow
fig=px.imshow(iris_correlations)

fig.update_layout(
    coloraxis = dict(colorbar=dict(tickmode = 'linear',
                                   dtick = 0.5
                                  )
                    )
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: @JohannesWiesner Thank you for accepting my suggestion. Is there anything you feel is missing with the answer?